# Multicore CPU abilities

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

Is it possible for multicore processor to run tasks from 2 different processes simultaneously(at same time).

Comment: This in fact is the common case. Only few programms support using multiple cores for one given task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the operating system supports it. The popular ones do and have done so for years.